# Can we write a series based on its first 5 terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

We are interested in formulating a function of $x$ as a series.
We know that, for example, the first five elements are
\begin{align}
i=1 &\rightarrow \frac{1}{(-1)^1(x-c)^1} \\
i=2 &\rightarrow \frac{n+m(x-c)}{(-1)^2(x-c)^2} \\
i=3 &\rightarrow \frac{n(3+n)+2nm(x-c)+m^2(x-c)^2}{(-1)^3(x-c)^3} \\
i=4 &\rightarrow \frac{n(8+n(5+n))+nm(5+3n)(x-c)+3nm^2(x-c)^2+m^3(x-c)^3 }{(-1)^4(x-c)^4} \\
i=5 &\rightarrow \frac{n(5+n)(6+n(4+n))+2nm(3+n)(3+2n)(x-c)}{(-1)^5(x-c)^5}\\
& \qquad +\frac{3nm^2(3+2n)(x-c)^2+4nm^3(x-c)^3+m^4(x-c)^4}{(-1)^5(x-c)^5}
\end{align}

I though maybe I can use binomial theorem in the numerator and maybe we should have something like
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{-i}\frac{X}{(x-c)^i}.$$

But I can't figure $X$ out. It seems like there's a pattern but I don't see it yet. Is there a general way to for problems like this?

**EDIT**

There were some miscalculations that I have corrected and following the notations proposed by *Claude Leibovici* and with some simplifications, we can rewrite these terms as
\begin{align}
i=1 &\rightarrow \frac{1}{(-1)^1x^1} \\
i=2 &\rightarrow \frac{n+mx}{(-1)^2x^2} \\
i=3 &\rightarrow \frac{3n+(n+mx)^2}{(-1)^3x^3} \\
i=4 &\rightarrow \frac{n(8+5n+5mx)+(n+mx)^3}{(-1)^4x^4} \\
i=5 &\rightarrow \frac{n(30+9n^2+9mx(2+mx)+2n(13+9mx))+(n+mx)^4}{(-1)^5x^5}
\end{align}

Comment: What does "the first five elements" mean?

Comment: @jc5535. The first terms

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. I updated the title accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand what your function is and what general way you're hoping for. Why isnt $\sum_n g_n$ where $g_1 = \text{ your function}$ and $g_k=0$  for $k\ge 2$ the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $r_i$ the terms you gave, replace $(x-c)$ by $x$ for the time being and let $s_i=(-1)^i r_i\,x^i$.

So, we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
i & s_i \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & m x +n \\
 3 & m^2 x^2+2 m n x+n (n+2) \\
 4 & m^3 x^3+3 m^2 n x^2+m n (3 n+5) x+n (n+2) (n+3) \\
 5 & m^4 x^4+4 m^3 n x^3+3 m^2 n (2 n+3) x^2+2 m n (n+3) (2 n+3) x+n (n+2) (n+3) (n+4)
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, the coefficient of the highest power term is $m^{i-1}$

The coefficient of the next term  is $(i-1) n m^{i-2}$

I do not see the next but, may be, there are typo's. But this is the general idea.

**After the edit**

Again, $r_i$ being your expressions, $s_i=(-1)^i r_i\,x^i$, let $y=n+mx$ to get
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & y \\
 3 & y^2+3 n \\
 4 & y^3+5 n y+8 n \\
 5 & y^4+9 n y^2+18 n y+8 n^2+30 n
\end{array}
\right)$$

which looks better but not sufficient for pattern identification. Would $s_6$ start with $y^5+15ny^3+\cdots$ ?

Comment: Thank you. There were some miscalculations. I have added an edit in which, I corrected the problems. It led to further simplifications. But I'm having a problem seeing any pattern in the first term of the numerators from $i=3$ onwards!

Comment: Unfortunately no but I see the general idea. Thank you.